# Equivalent of MySQL Sum(X) group by Y in Crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

This is how my report looks like now :

[image]

I'd like the `Quantity` summed up for each `Product` , similar to how we do it in a SQL query :

```
select product_id ,sum(quantity) from my_table group by product_id;
```

This is the desired output :

| product | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Aluminuim | 204 |
| Bois | 216 |
| Dynamo Bicyclette | 36 |
| Guidon Bicyclette | 12 |
| Necklace string | 5,530 |

Comment: Are you familiar with "grouping" in Crystal Reports? It might be helpful to spend some minutes to read through the basic concepts of the tool, e.g here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/dfc124becfa845ffa91b1e717b20e3ec/2020/en-US/47788d716e041014910aba7db0e91070.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to simply insert a CrossTab. Use the Product as the row element and Quantity as the metric to sum.